# Abstract methods inside SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am reading the documentation of android

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Almost all the public methods are declared as abstract : such as;

```
public abstract boolean getBoolean (String key, boolean defValue)
public abstract Map<String, ?> getAll ()
public abstract float getFloat (String key, float defValue
```

My question is that, we call the shared preference like this inside our app/activities.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

We never extend it to be forced to use the methods that are abstract. How does it work ?

Comment: Though it doesn't directly answer your question as to where the methods are implemented, it should be noted that `SharedPreferences` is an interface, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

you've used PreferenceManager to initialize your SharedPreferences so it's a subclass which implements those methods before you instantiate your Shared Preferences

Comment: so PreferenceManager takes care of that job for us ? and saves the hassle of instantiation? It is also somehow weird that there is no reference about the PreferenceManager inside the documentation page of SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the docs you can see that SharedPreference is a `public interface`.  It is not a class.  Android doesn't want you to see the underlying class implementing this interface which is why they have factory methods such as `getSharedPreferences()` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to give you one.

edit: It's also worth noting that `Context.getSharedPreferences()` is an abstract method which is then implemented in subclasses such as `Activity.getSharedPreferences()`.